# Insert number id into primary key column using Typeorm EntityManager API

Tags: javascript, sql-server, typeorm, graphql-js

I am trying to insert number id into primary column of User table using Typeorm to build graphql resolver, but get Error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I've tried to `set identity_insert on`, but no luck

```
await em.query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT User ON")
await em.create(User, newUser)
```

Some suggest to combine the two queries into online, but I don't know how to do it in Typeorm.
I know it may be possible to write raw query to combine them. I am wondering if there is an elegent way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the solution for me is to write raw sql:

```
await em.query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT User ON;" + 
"insert into user(id, firstname, lastname, username, password) " +
"values(@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)", [variables...]
```

Hope this solution can help somebody working with Typeorm and MS SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the commands inside a transaction.

```
const em = getManager();
await em.transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
    await transactionalEntityManager.query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT User ON");
    await transactionalEntityManager.create(User, newUser);
    await transactionalEntityManager.query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT User OFF");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I still got the same error when I call save(). It might be MS SQL server issue as I can use your code to create but got the error when I try to save the user into ms sql server.

Comment: So, you want to create or update or both?

Comment: I am trying to persist new user after create it as followed:  `await transactionalEntityManager.query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT User ON");
    const user = await transactionalEntityManager.create(User, newUser);
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(user);
    await transactionalEntityManager.query("SET IDENTITY_INSERT User OFF");` If I only create user by calling create. The new user is not going to be persisted into mssql database.